# How to combine rows of pandas dataframe only for the first column?

Tags: python, pandas

```
most_wickets_2021 = pd.read_html("https://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/records/bowling/most_wickets_career.html?id=13781;type=tournament")[0]
most_wickets_2021
```

[Link to where I got the data from](https://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/records/bowling/most_wickets_career.html?id=13781;type=tournament)

This code prints out a dataframe that looks like this: [image of the dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDolX.png)

How do I make it so the player's team just shows up in the first column right next to their name, instead of showing up in every column as a new row?
Ex:

| Player | Mat |
| --- | --- |
| Shahnawaz Dahani (Multan Sultans) | 11 |

I didn't type every column but I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: I would do as follows: 1, make two subsets from the dataframe, one indexed on even columns (use .loc[lambda d: d.index %2==0]), one on the odd -- these are the team names, and you'll only need this to be a one column dataframe (rename the column = team), 2, concat the two dataframes back into one (after reset_index on both), 3, assign player as a combination of player name and the "team" column gained from step 2

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple for loop process then "looking ahead" to the line that has the team, here is a possible simple way you could accomplish that.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html("https://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/records/bowling/most_wickets_career.html?id=13781;type=tournament")[0]

print('Player/Team                      ', '\t\t\t', 'Mat', '\t', 'Inns')

for x in range(len(df) - 1):
    if ((x %2) == 0):
        print(df['Player'][x], df['Player'][x + 1], '\t\t\t', df['Mat'][x], '\t', df['Inns'][x])
```

Basically, this code snippet is reading through the data frame and for every other row, it is grabbing data either from the first row which has the player stats or from the subsequent row for the team name.

Here is a sampling of the output from my terminal when this program was run.

```
@Una:~/Python_Programs/Cricket$ python3 Cricket.py 
Player/Team                                  Mat     Inns
Shahnawaz Dahani (Multan Sultans)            11      11
Wahab Riaz (Peshawar Zalmi)              12      12
Shaheen Shah Afridi (Lahore Qalandars)           10      10
JP Faulkner (Lahore Qalandars)           6   6
Imran Tahir (Multan Sultans)             7   7
Hasan Ali (Islamabad United)             10      10
S Mahmood (Peshawar Zalmi)           5   5
Imran Khan (Multan Sultans)              7   7
Mohammad Wasim (Islamabad United)            11      11
```

I didn't do too much work on formatting, but that should be easily cleaned up.  You can try this method out and/or wait to see if someone has a more elegant way to do this.

Hope that helps.

Regards.

Comment: I don't see `.iloc` used anywhere in your code

Comment: Sorry.  You are right.  I had used it initially to get every other row, but then went with the for loop and used the index instead.  By error.

Comment: Just an addition.  To address the reference to "iloc" that actually was not used in my final iteration, I updated my answer so as to not confuse anyone reviewing this issue.  Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame(most_wickets_2021["Player"].values.reshape(-1,2))
res = pd.DataFrame({
    "Player": data[0] + " " + data[1],
    })
data = pd.DataFrame(most_wickets_2021[most_wickets_2021.columns[1:]].values[:,:][::2])
data.columns = most_wickets_2021.columns[1:]
pd.concat([res, data], axis=1)
```